# Combining multiple seaborn heatmaps together

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

My DataFrame:

```
    A   B   Up  Down    p
0   1   x   A   A   0.5
1   1   x   T   T   0.5
2   1   y   G   G   0.5
3   1   y   C   C   0.5
4   2   x   A   A   0.5
5   2   x   T   T   0.5
6   2   y   G   G   0.5
7   2   y   C   C   0.5
```

Code:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': {0: 1,1: 1,2: 1,3: 1,4: 2,5: 2,6: 2,7: 2},
     'B': {0: 'x',1: 'x',2: 'y',3: 'y',4: 'x',5: 'x',6: 'y',7: 'y'},
     'Up': {0: 'A', 1: 'T', 2: 'G', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5: 'T', 6: 'G', 7: 'C'},
     'Down': {0: 'A', 1: 'T', 2: 'G', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5: 'T', 6: 'G', 7: 'C'},
     'p': {0: 0.5,1: 0.5,2: 0.5,3: 0.5,4: 0.5,5: 0.5,6: 0.5,7: 0.5}})
```

I am trying to use seaborn to plot out a heatmap of the above dataset. I can generate individual heatplots by manually looping through unique combinations of columns `A` and `B` but I would like to have them all in the same plot as `sns.FacetGrid` enables.

I would like to generate individual heatplots for each combination of columns `A` and `B`. Each of those heatplots should use `Up` as the y-axis and `Down` as the x-axis. Values for each square within the heatplots should use column `p`.

I would also like to be able to control the coloration for the range of `p` values. The way I'm currently doing this is with something like the following:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
lognorm = LogNorm(vmin=1.0 / (10.0 ** 200), vmax=1.0)
ax = sns.heatmap(df, norm = lognorm,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `FacetGrid` with `'A'` and `'B'` for rows and columns.
Then the `axes_dict` of that `FacetGrid` will contain a subplot (`ax`) for each combination of `'A'` and `'B'`. These `'A'` and `'B'` can be used to take a subset of the dataframe as input for a pivot table.

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='A', col='B')
lognorm = LogNorm(vmin=1.0 / (10.0 ** 200), vmax=1.0)
for (a, b), ax in g.axes_dict.items():
    sns.heatmap(df[(df['A'] == a) & (df['B'] == b)].pivot('Up', 'Down', 'p'), norm=lognorm, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'A={a} B={b}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @JohanC, it works really nicely. The only issue I have is that when plotting I lose the information from the `A` and `B` columns, such that I cannot tell which heatmap corresponds to which column. Is it possible annotate each heatmap by their `A` and `B` column groups?

Comment: You could try something like `ax.set_title(f'A={a} B={b}')` in the loop (see edited answer).